# Why installed memory not the same as "total memory"

Tags: linux, memory-usage, linux-mint

I am running linux (Mint 17) on new laptop (Asus X550ZA) that has 8gb of RAM.  The bios shows 8gb, but when I show /proc/meminfo, it only shows 3.4 gb:

```
 $ sudo cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:        3411176 kB
MemFree:          122224 kB
MemAvailable:    1924580 kB
```

When I show the physical memory installed it shows the 8GB.  So what has happened to my other 4.5 GB of memory?  What is allocating this? Oh, I am running a 64 bit OS (Linux gregh-X550ZA 3.19.0-33-generic #38~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 6 18:17:28 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux)

```
$ sudo dmidecode --type memory

Handle 0x0031, DMI type 16, 23 bytes
Physical Memory Array
    Location: System Board Or Motherboard
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: None
    Maximum Capacity: 8 GB
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Number Of Devices: 2

Handle 0x0033, DMI type 17, 40 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0031
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 4096 MB
    Form Factor: SODIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM 0
    Bank Locator: CHANNEL A
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered)
    Speed: 1600 MHz
    Manufacturer: Hynix/Hyundai
    Serial Number: 1219ADB5
    Asset Tag: A1_AssetTagNum0
    Part Number: HMT451S6BFR8A-PB  
    Rank: 1
    Configured Clock Speed: 1600 MHz
    Minimum voltage:  1.350 V
    Maximum voltage:  1.500 V
    Configured voltage:  1.500 V

Handle 0x0034, DMI type 17, 40 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0031
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 4096 MB
    Form Factor: SODIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM 0
    Bank Locator: CHANNEL B
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered)
    Speed: 1600 MHz
    Manufacturer: Hynix/Hyundai
    Serial Number: 1259ADB8
    Asset Tag: A1_AssetTagNum1
    Part Number: HMT451S6BFR8A-PB  
    Rank: 1
    Configured Clock Speed: 1600 MHz
    Minimum voltage:  1.350 V
    Maximum voltage:  1.500 V
    Configured voltage:  1.500 V
```

Comment: Looking at your laptop specs, it looks like you have an `AMD A10-7400P` processor, which has an integrated Radeon GPU. The missing memory could be taken up by that. I would check your BIOS for a setting related to it.

Comment: Your operating system can only use what's exposed to it by the underlying subsystem (the firmware/BIOS), so basically what @Kassandry said.

Comment: The bios doesn't allow me access to configure the chipset.  I figured the ugpu was allocating the memory, but how do I control it and why us it allocating so much ...4.5 GB